# Passagem de parâmetro com valor na assinatura

Tags: javascript

Estou com duvida, na verdade não lembro nem como se fala/escreve isto porém, preciso de passar um valor padrão no parametro, então ficaria assim o:

```
function umvalor(valor = null)
```

Pois se eu passar um valor ele irá assumir este valor, se não o valor padrão dele será null.

Como fazer isto em javascript, se tiver como ne.